# Module to add keyword search capability to content admin page?

Tags: 7, search, nodes, users

Is there any module or technique for D7 that can provide this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Admin VBO Views](http://drupal.org/project/admin_vbo_views) module provides a complementary content admin page, with a search by title (and other fields) enabled by default.

It wouldn't take much to edit the View provided by that module to provide further exposed filters to search the content with.